# Change color of bullets within an ExampleBlock

Tags: beamer, color, itemize

I have redefined the color of my `exampleblock`s using the following code"

```
\definecolor{trueblue}{RGB}{0, 115, 197}
\setbeamercolor*{block title example}{bg=trueblue}
```

However, the bullets within the `exampleblock`s still appear in the default green color.
I experimented with perturbation of:

```
\setbeamercolor{block itemize item example}{fg= trueblue}
```

but nothing seems to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

Set the `itemize item` color:

```
\setbeamercolor{itemize item}{fg=trueblue}
```

If the change must apply only inside the `exampleblock` environment, you can use the `etoolbox` package and its `\AtBeginEnvironment`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\definecolor{trueblue}{RGB}{0, 115, 197} 
\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[circle]
\setbeamercolor*{block title example}{bg=trueblue}
\AtBeginEnvironment{exampleblock}{\setbeamercolor{itemize item}{fg=trueblue}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{exampleblock}{Test}
\begin{itemize}
\item First item.
\end{itemize}
\end{exampleblock}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

For second and third level `itemize` environments you will also need

```
\setbeamercolor{itemize subitem}{fg=trueblue}
\setbeamercolor{itemize subsubitem}{fg=trueblue}
```