# Background color of Markdown blocks

Tags: color, markdown

I want to be able to insert Markdown text in a LaTeX document with a simple macro, and I want that text to always have a specific background color (e.g. light gray).

I tried using the [`markdown`](https://ctan.org/pkg/markdown?lang=en) package some of the solutions listed below without luck:

- [Change background color for text block](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/238294/change-background-color-for-text-block)
- [Change color and background behind text of all 'description' environments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63030/change-color-and-background-behind-text-of-all-description-environments?rq=1)
- [Color of enumerate/itemize items in alertblocks and exampleblocks (beamer theme Torino)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/229756/color-of-enumerate-itemize-items-in-alertblocks-and-exampleblocks-beamer-theme?rq=1)

I think the challenge that I am facing is that markdown is itself a block.

Here's a MWE where I am trying to use a custom background color for the Markdown block (e.g. light gray).

Ideally the solution is some sort of macro, e.g. `mymarkdown`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{markdown}

\usepackage{lipsum}  

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{markdown}
This is now inside Markdown

## Here is a Markdown list
+ Create a list by starting a line with `+`, `-`, or `*`
+ Sub-lists are made by indenting 2 spaces:
  - Marker character change forces new list start:
    * Ac tristique libero volutpat at
    + Facilisis in pretium nisl aliquet
    - Nulla volutpat aliquam velit
+ Very easy!

## Here are some Markdown blockquotes
> Blockquotes can also be nested...
>> ...by using additional greater-than signs right next to each other...
> > > ...or with spaces between arrows.][1]][1]


\end{markdown}

This is now outside of Markdown
\begin{itemize}
    \item Item 1
    \item Item 2
    \item Item 3
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why not just put it all in a `tcolorbox` environment?

Comment: @DavidPurton It seems not be as easy as you say (if, as I guess, the OP will create a new environment for his task). With `\newenvironment{colormarkdown}{\begin{tcolorbox}\begin{markdown}}{\end{markdown}\end{tcolorbox}}` and `\begin{colormarkdown} ... \end{colormarkdown}`, you will get `LaTeX Error: \begin{tcb@savebox} on input line ...  ended by \end{document}.` and the compilation ended with `! Emergency stop.` and `!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!`.

Comment: @quark67, it is a pain to create a new environment because the markdown environment looks for an explicit `\end{markdown}` and this will never occur but you can just do `\begin{tcolorbox}\begin{markdown}...\end{markdown}\end{tcolorbox}`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `tcolorbox` and coerce `markdown` into opening a `tcolorbox` before doing its business, issuing `\end{tcolorbox}` at the end.

Add the desired options to the starting `\begin{tcolorbox}` (look at the very detailed manual).

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{markdown}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\pretocmd{\markdown}{\begin{tcolorbox}}{}{}
\def\endmarkdown{\end{tcolorbox}}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

%\begin{tcolorbox}
\begin{markdown}
This is now inside Markdown

## Here is a Markdown list
+ Create a list by starting a line with `+`, `-`, or `*`
+ Sub-lists are made by indenting 2 spaces:
  - Marker character change forces new list start:
    * Ac tristique libero volutpat at
    + Facilisis in pretium nisl aliquet
    - Nulla volutpat aliquam velit
+ Very easy!

## Here are some Markdown blockquotes
> Blockquotes can also be nested...
>> ...by using additional greater-than signs right next to each other...
> > > ...or with spaces between arrows.][1]][1]


\end{markdown}
%\end{tcolorbox}

This is now outside of Markdown
\begin{itemize}
    \item Item 1
    \item Item 2
    \item Item 3
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]