# How to create a gray background for text like we do in markdown?

Tags: backgrounds, highlighting

My question actually has two parts:

1- How can I create a gray background for a paragraph like this using latex?

```
Lorem ipsum
Lorem ipsum
Lorem ipsum
Lorem ipsum
```

2- How can I highlight just a little part of the text like this using latex?

Lorem ipsum `Lorem ipsum` Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum.

**Edit 1:** Markdown package got recommended to me below but below package does not use block quotes or highlights. Is it possible to use them with markdown package and if it is how?

**Edit 2:** I am now able to create gray background blocks using `tcolorbox` but I stil cannot highlight small groups of texts(1 or 2 words)(2. question still unanswered)

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/529616/background-color-of-markdown-blocks

Comment: Sorry that doesn't help. Is there a link where they use block quotes and highlights with markdown package. I tried it like markdown after adding markdown package with (`) symbols  but it did not work.

Comment: Markdown is written in pure text editors. I just ask, after you process markdown, in which format and with which instructions you get a gray background on some text? Can you clarify?

Comment: It answers my 1st question but It doesnt help me on the 2nd question. @PhelypeOleinik

Comment: @djnavas. I was able to create gray backgrounds for entire paragraphs using `tcolorbox`. But I am not able to create gray background(highlight) for a word or 2. like I did in this comment for highlighting `tcolorbox` using latex.

Comment: @ErselHengirmen Try `\tcbox{some highlighted text}`

Comment: I am not that much familliar with markdown package, but if you use only latex, there are 3 ways to get text highlighting as you want: Packages `soul`, or `lua-ul` or drawing highlighted regions with tikz. From my point of view, the easiest is to use `lua-ul`.